# How to execute a section only when user is logged in else skip the section?

Tags: magento2, header

I have these codes for account link. How can I change the code in phtml account link section so that if user is not logged in the acount link section code will not execute else it will execute.

app/design/.... /account-links.phtml

```
<?php if ($accountLinksHtml): ?>
<div id="header-account" class="account-links top-links links-wrapper-separators-left skip-content skip-content--style">
    <?php echo $accountLinksHtml; ?>
</div>
```

app/code/...... /account-links.php

```
class AccountLinks extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Theme helper
     *
     * @var HelperData
     */
    protected $theme;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param HelperData $helperData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        HelperData $helperData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->theme = $helperData;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

   /**
     * Get helper
     *
     * @return HelperData
     */
    public function getHelperTheme()
    {
        return $this->theme;
    }

}
```

[image: this is the error I am getting if I add the public function in Accountlinks.php]

Comment: please explain briefly.

Comment: I have designed a custom theme. In the header section it shows My Account in general. I want to remove that for guest user. In the phtml file under app/design I have this section of code which fetches the my account. I want to execute this only if user is logged in otherwise I dont want this section to execute. So how do I put a check condition before this that if logged in then execute else not

Comment: in your phtml you can get or check your customer is logged in or not ?

Comment: please share screenshot to understand better.

Comment: In your custom theme which phtml file use? Or what is the path of your phtml file?

Comment: I have updated my query?

Comment: share your update block and phtml code..

Comment: your phtml file path is different than your block file please check

Answer (score 1):

### **In your Block File**

```
class AccountLinks extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Theme helper
     *
     * @var HelperData
     */
    protected $theme;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param HelperData $helperData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
        HelperData $helperData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->theme = $helperData;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

   /**
     * Get helper
     *
     * @return HelperData
     */
    public function getHelperTheme()
    {
        return $this->theme;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }

}
```

### **In your Phtml files**

```
<?php if($block->isLoggedIn()) {
   // Logged in, You can make your changes here
} else {
   // Not logged in
} ?>
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: Do I have to call the block file from any layout file?

Comment: you can add this code to your block file (`AccountLinks.php`)

Comment: ok. I will implement it.

Comment: but this class in AccountLinks.php is already extending some other class. Can you provide me the entire the file how it can be added in the AccountLinks.php

Comment: it's the same class `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. check updated answer

Comment: so I just have to add the constructor and function

Comment: yes you just need to add remaining classes to your construct

Comment: I am having an error I am attaching the image in my post.

Comment: This is the error I am getting so what should I do.

Comment: define namespace in your block

Comment: I have done it already. its there

Comment: still same error?

Comment: no namespace was already there. and its correct I checked still giving the error.

Comment: do you have any layout file?

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention the block file is contained in app/code/Infortis/Base/Block/Html/Header/AccountLinks.php. but when I add this path in phtml I got the error invalid block type

Comment: no in view I just have the js files

Comment: do you have the same namespace in `AccountLinks.php` like `Infortis/Base/Block/Html/Header`? show your `AccountLinks.php` file

Comment: <?php
/**
 * Account links
 */

namespace Infortis\Base\Block\Html\Header;

use Infortis\Base\Helper\Data as HelperData;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

this is the top portion

Comment: I think its getting the error in the phtml file where I add: <?php $moduleBlock= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Infortis\Base\Block\AccountLinks.php'); ?>  before the condition check. But if I give the actual path it shows invalid path type

Comment: move the conversation in to chat, we can discuss there

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96591/discussion-on-answer-by-mohit-rane-how-to-execute-a-section-only-when-user-is-lo).

Answer (score 0):

you could use below code to check,

**Use of objectmanager is not recommended**

Try injecting customer session in block file and call block function from phtml

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Comment: "Try injecting customer session in block file and call block function from phtml" how this is done can you provide me a detailed solution. and the above section of code is added in the app/design section.

Comment: First check whether it is working or not by using objectmanger. It can be added in phtml itself. Add above code in your phtml

Comment: I am editing my post and giving the details of both the files. please suggest me how it can be done. this method is not loading giving an error

Comment: using object manager can you provide the syntax. I am completely new and I do not know how to implement the nested if which contains an html in between.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: as of now I am getting syntax error

Comment: <?php $moduleBlock= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Infortis\Base\Block\Sessionaccountlinks.php'); ?>


<?php if ($moduleBlock->isCustomerLoggedIn()) : ?>
<?php if ($accountLinksHtml): ?>
    <div id="header-account" class="account-links top-links links-wrapper-separators-left skip-content skip-content--style">
        <?php echo $accountLinksHtml; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: I have created a block file then how to use two if s together?

Answer (score 0):

How do you inject the client session into the block file? Can you explain me better? I have a similar problem.
I need to restrict all products with a restriction flag for the customer to be able to purchase it only if they are logged in.

Comment: You can make use event observer (controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add). You can check whether customer logged in or not.

Comment: Let me know if you need any example

Comment: I believe I will need an example. It's still foggy this subject for me

Comment: checkout this example..https://webkul.com/blog/restrict-add-cart-according-condition-magneto2/